# How to transit to other routes using the same component without destroying and reinitializing Component?

Tags: angular, router

I have a ProfileComponent, inside the page user can click on letters to filter profile start with it.

Entry Point: `/profile`

`A B C ... X Y Z`

When user click on these letters ->  url: `/profile` -> `/profile/;startWith=X`.

I want to keep the `startWith` parameters in URL, however I notice Angular 2 will destroy current component then recreate and initialize the same component again. How to keep URL params without reinitializing component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

```
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
```

in your component, the router should keep the same instance instead of re-creating a new one.